How to obtain the Cloud Messaging server key to be able to send push notifications between mobile devices? Android - Flutter
I am trying to get a mobile device to send a push notification to another following a course.
In the image you can see that in the course I am following the cloud messaging server key appears

But when I go to my project and look for the server key it does not appear as seen in the second image

The main code I have made is the following
Future<void> sendMessage(String to, Map<String, dynamic> data, String title, String body) async{
  await http.post(
      'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=    '
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            'notification': <String, dynamic>{
              'body': 'This is the content',
              'title': 'This is the title',
            },
            'priority': 'high',
            'ttl': '4500',
            'data': data,
            'to': to
          }
      )

  );

}

In the 'authorization' field would be the server key that I want to obtain.. My question is how do I obtain this key?
Any help is useful, thank you.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Please be careful showing pictures which shows keys that can be private keys

Also it is a very bad idea to put a server key into your app where it is possible that someone can get it and take over your push messaging. Its called a server key for a reason

This FCM server key is no longer available, which is also what is explained in the text under the "API de Cloud Messaging (heredada)" heading. ¯_(ツ)_/¯ As @tyczj also answered below, there is no (nor has there ever been a) way to securely send messages from one device to another directly through FCM. Sending messages requires admin-level credentials and should only be done from a trusted environment.

You are referencing an example that is no longer accurate and using the deprecated Cloud Messaging API.
Please read the documentation and you will see how to generate a new key.
Again, this key should NOT be put into your app and it is a PRIVATE key, if someone were to get a hold of this key they could send messages to your app without you knowing
